# XAML PathTooLongException

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I have recently added my project to TFS and I am getting an Unhandled Exception

**System.IO.PathTooLongException**
The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

The XAML Designer doesn't load. I am able to compile and run the code but the XAML Designer doesn't work.
Project path is "C:\Work\"

Thank you

Adding the screenshot of the pages

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I think the path is obviously longer than what you think.  I would look in the debugger when the XAML file is trying to be loaded, look at the generated code in the *.g.cs files, etc.

Comment: I have added the screenshots and I checked the XamlTypeInfo.g.cs and the FullyQualifiedName for the app was around 80 chars

Comment: Cleared the contents of ShadowCache but still didn't work
(C:\Users\Raghav\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Designer\ShadowCache)

Everything that is on my desktop is moving into these folders.(I remember dragging and dropping Images folder from desktop to my solution explorer but donno why all the files in desktop are getting copied)

Moved all the contents of desktop to a diff location and now it is working